# Find the single non-nan value in a multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

EDIT: I noticed that I simplified my problem too much. This is probably because I assumed that the proposed solutions would work in a similar way as my original brute-force solution. I changed the multiindex to better show my problems. My apologies for those who have already put effort in it, thank you so much!

I have a pandas dataframe that is multi-indexed. Let's say the index has three levels, the second level contains the name of a color. I know that in each row all column which have the `blue` color in the index contain `NaN` except a single one, so it looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iterables = [['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ["red", "blue", "green"], ['one', 'two']]
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 24), columns=mi)
df[("bar", "blue","one")] = [2     , np.nan, np.nan, 3     , np.nan]
df[("baz", "blue","two")] = [np.nan, 4.4   , np.nan, np.nan, 5     ]
df[("qux", "blue","one")] = [np.nan, np.nan, 1     , np.nan, np.nan]
```

Output:

```
        bar                                               ...       qux                                             
        red           blue               green            ...       red           blue               green          
        one       two  one       two       one       two  ...       one       two  one       two       one       two
0  0.046326 -0.999092  2.0  0.073113  0.958438  0.276653  ... -0.258202 -0.772636  NaN -0.639735  1.438262 -0.033578
1  0.257776 -2.499286  NaN  0.854263 -0.037380 -0.571258  ...  1.656198 -1.110911  NaN  0.757692  0.498118  1.070371
2 -0.314146  0.941367  NaN  0.265850 -0.153231 -1.092106  ... -0.208089 -0.363624  1.0  0.046457 -2.158373  0.572496
3 -1.198977  0.605490  3.0 -0.790985  0.000563 -0.958261  ...  1.339086 -1.057270  NaN -0.355639  1.050980 -1.727684
4 -0.562230 -1.721894  NaN  0.856543 -1.137364  1.185481  ...  0.986215  1.028128  NaN -0.264889  0.571484 -0.505340
```

Now I want to create a new dataframe that contains the non-nan value that the row has in the respective column and also names the other indices of that multi index.

```
    word number blue
0   bar  one    2.0
1   baz  two    4.4
2   qux  one    1.0
3   bar  one    3.0
4   baz  two    5.0
```

i.e. the `word` and `number` entries of the new dataframe should be the indeces in which the original dataframe had the non-nan value and the new `blue` column should contain the values.

I have a brute-force solution where I iterate over basically every entry, but my final dataframe will contain around 2000 columns, which will then take very long to run.

Comment: Should we assume that 'red','green' columns are everywhere NA? i.e. every column other than one single 'blue' column is NA.

Comment: @smci, I added code to produce a dataframe with the properties. Also my original example was misleading, the other columns can also contain floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If select by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) then only reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), remove first Multiindex level by `reset_index` with `drop=True` and last convert `Series` to `2` columns `DataFrame` by [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = (df.xs('blue', axis=1, level=1)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
        .rename_axis('number')
        .reset_index(name='blue'))
print (df)
   number  blue
0       1   2.0
1       2   4.4
2       3   1.0
3       1   3.0
4       2   5.0
```

EDIT: Solution is similar, only filtered at least one `NaN`s columns by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then is used [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) by both `MultiIndex` levels:

```
df1 = (df.loc[:, df.isna().any()]
         .xs('blue', axis=1, level=1)
         .stack([0,1])
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .rename_axis(('word','number'))
         .reset_index(name='blue'))

print (df1)
  word number  blue
0  bar    one   2.0
1  baz    two   4.4
2  qux    one   1.0
3  bar    one   3.0
4  baz    two   5.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I noticed that I cannot reproduce the solution in my case, because I simplified the original case too much, sorry for that. I will rephrase my question.

Answer (score 1):

You could stack one single level, only keep the `blue` column, and drop NaN values:

```
resul = df.stack(level=0)['blue'].reset_index(level=1).rename(columns={'level_1': 'number'}).dropna()
```

It gives:

```
   number  blue
0       1   2.0
1       2   4.4
2       3   1.0
3       1   3.0
4       2   5.0
```

---

For the edited question, it looks that you want to only process columns containing NaN values and only keep non NaN one. This could do the trick:

```
df.loc[:,df.isna().any()].stack(level=[0,2])[['blue']].dropna()
```

It gives:

```
           blue
0 bar one   2.0
1 baz two   4.4
2 qux one   1.0
3 bar one   3.0
4 baz two   5.0
```

NB: if you keep other columns, you will get much more results for `blue` values...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I noticed that I cannot reproduce the solution in my case, because I simplified the original case too much, sorry for that. I will rephrase my question.

Answer (score 0):

You may check with two stack chain

```
df.stack().stack().reset_index()
   level_0 level_1  level_2     0
0        0    blue        1   2.2
1        1    blue        2   5.0
2        2    blue        1  44.0
3        3    blue        3   3.3
4        4    blue        1   1.0
5        5    blue        3   1.0
```

Comment: Btw this assumes that 'red','green' columns are everywhere NA.